# Asus Xtion, Stream RGB and IR together

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, openni-launch, ir

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently trying out the Asus Xtion Pro Live using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I start the asus xtion using openni_launch, I get this error:

Cannot stream RGB and IR at the same time. Streaming RGB only.

I thought the Asus Xtion was different from the Kinect because the Xtion allows for RGB and IR Streaming at the same time. Why can I not stream them at the same time?

Should I use a different package or something?  I did read though some of the ROS answers but it doesn't seem that anyone has tried this or it wasn't important enough.  Is it possible to stream the RGB and IR together on the Asus Xtion?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64946/asus-xtion,--stream-rgb-and-ir-together/) by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-06-12**:
I'm missing the error you are seeing when you use openni_launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Asus or Kinect does not stream RGB and IR at the same time, it is sent out sequentially.
Thus working with the IR and RGB frames which have very close time stamps is the way adopted to solve this issue.

You can get more info in the link below at section 4. Time Synchronizer

http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-06-12**:
How can http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/ExtrinsicCalibration be used efficiently?  Should I write code that takes in the RGB and IR Image, synchronize the images by using the Time Synchronizer, then publish those synchronized images?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-06-12**:
plz go thru this http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/ExtrinsicCalibrationExternal

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-06-13**:
That is for external RGB with the Depth on the Kinect.  Its not the same as with the on-board RGB camera and the Depth.  The extrinsic calibration is quite bad doing the tutorial I posted, in which, I want to be able to move the checkerboard around the image instead of keeping it static.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-06-13**:
I guess there wont be any need to write a code to calibrate RGB and IR camera of kinect,

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-12-29**:
Is there a way to eliminate the depth functionality, and only use RGB and IR? I have multiple looking at the same space from multiple angles, and I want to eliminate interference.